# Intent Redirection Vulnerability Android

Tags: android-security

My application has been reject by google for 1 week for this reason. The information written on what exactly should I do is not clear. Has anyone encountered this situation before, please help?
https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9267555
Best wishes[image]

Comment: It says there is a problem with startActivityForResult but which one I can not understand from the message. Is there somewhere on the developer console where can I get more information about my code ?

Comment: Hi @Okan, were you able to figure out the issue? I am facing the same with androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult. For your 1st point, you can generate build of required environment -> outputs -> mapping.txt file and search for the line. You will get from which library.

Comment: Hi @shakunthalaMK We solved the problem. We are using a payment sdk called BKM, this caused the problem. We updated the version of this sdk and problem solved. In google documents they suggest 3 different suggestions. You can try them, however in my opinion 4th and the most important one is checking your dependencies. Check all of them, check the issues of your dependencies on Github and update the latest version if possible.

Comment: Hi Okan and @shakunthalaMK. Please share how to find the affected library

Comment: hi, check your dependencies on their own Github page. For me, there was an issue opened for BKM on Github and we solved our problem. Sometimes they can write details about this kind of issues.  Firstly check all of them then update all your dependencies with the latest version.